# CSS3 animation issue in Firefox and IE

Tags: css, animation, transform

I'm trying to scale, rotate and translate an element using CSS3 animation. This animation works as expected in chrome but i'm unable to reproduce it in Firefox and IE10.

In FF and IE, only the scale transformation works on element when using:

```
transform: scale(.3) rotate(360deg) translateY(30px) translateX(10px);
```

Here a jsFiddle which reproduces this issue:

### [DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyTC4/)

This is the HTML part:

```
<div class="preloader"> 
    <i></i>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
.preloader {   
    width:240px;
    height:30px
}
.preloader i {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color:transparent;
    width:29px;
    height:29px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    -webkit-animation: test 1s infinite linear;
    -webkit-transform:scale(0);
    -ms-animation: test 1s infinite linear;
    -ms-transform:scale(0);
    animation: test 1s infinite linear;
    transform:scale(0);
    border-radius:30px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.preloader i {
    left:0;
    -webkit-animation-delay:0.52s;
    -ms-animation-delay:0.52s;
    animation-delay:0.52s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes test {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(1);
        background-color:#A300A3;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform:scale(.3) rotate(360deg) translateY(30px) translateX(10px);
        background-color:transparent;
        border-color:transparent;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes test {
    0% {
        -ms-transform:scale(1);
        background-color:#A300A3;
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform:scale(.3) rotate(360deg) translateY(30px) translateX(10px);
        background-color:transparent;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
}
@keyframes test {
    0% {
        transform:scale(1);
        background-color:#A300A3;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(.3) rotate(360deg) translateY(30px) translateX(10px);
        background-color:transparent;
        border-radius: 15px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but I really recommend [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) so you only write one piece of code in a more manageable form without having to write out each browser separately.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada Yes i know jQuery transit plugin which is a great one but i'm more looking for only CSS solution here. That's said, i'll try using it if i'm still unable to fix this issue but, i guess, i'm just missing something obvious. Thank you for your comment, i appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. IE doesn't [need](http://caniuse.com/css-animation) the `-ms` prefix for the `animation` property, so remove the `@-ms-keyframes` and `-ms-animation` rules.
2. You have to expand the `transform` shorthand on both the `.preloader i` selector and within the `@keyframes` rule to include the initial values for the properties you're animating: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xyTC4/5/)**

   ```
   .preloader i {
      -webkit-animation: test 1s infinite linear;
      -webkit-transform:scale(0);
       animation: test 1s infinite linear;
       transform: scale(0) rotate(0deg) translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
   }

   @keyframes test {        
       0% {
           transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg) translateY(0px) translateX(0px);
           background-color:#A300A3;
   }
       100% {
           transform: scale(.3) rotate(360deg) translateY(30px) translateX(10px);
           background-color:transparent;
           border-radius: 15px;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: For others looking if you have a similar issue, try `transform:translateZ(1px)` and perhaps also `transform:perspective(999px)`. These help the browser render the element more carefully, which is necessary at times

Comment: Thank you, works as expected! @ZachSaucier Thx too, i'll check that for sure